# How to apply a filter on a pandas DF based on column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF like the one below:

```
a b  c d  e
0 -1 2 -3 4
0 1 -2 3 -4
0 -1 -2 -3 4
```

and i need to select from each row only columns with positive values.

So the first row should return

```
a c e
0 2 4
```

the second row

```
a b. d
0 1 3
```

the third

```
a e 
0 4
```

anyone can help with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear in what form the results should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the results needs to be Series:

```py
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row[row >= 0])
    print()
```

Prints:

```
a    0
c    2
e    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64

a    0
b    1
d    3
Name: 1, dtype: int64

a    0
e    4
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

---

If DataFrames:

```py
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row[row >= 0].to_frame().T)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
   a  c  e
0  0  2  4

   a  b  d
1  0  1  3

   a  e
2  0  4
```